# How to get gallery to automatically move

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get this gallery to automatically move, but i cant find the command to do so in the script. Maybe i am missing something? Here is the script.

This is the script

http://syndicatebox.com/jquery.slidingGallery-1.2.min.js

I am using this script

http://www.meadmiracle.com/SlidingGallery.aspx

I am using this to call the script to work.
But i am unable of the function here to make it automatically slide without clicking.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('div.gallery img').slidingGallery({
            Lwidth: 400,
            Lheight: 300,
            Lshrink: function(dim) { return dim * 0.5; },
            gutterWidth: -8,
            container: $('div.gallery')     
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I dont think this script has autoSliding feature

Comment: Hmm is there any way i can implement it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am cross-posting my answer from https://stackoverflow.com/q/8250488/128165

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var autoSlideInterval;

    function start_autoslide(){
        autoSlideInterval = setInterval( function(){
            $.galleryUtility.slideLeft() ;
        }, 5000);
    }

    function stop_autoslide(){
        clearInterval( autoSlideInterval );
    }

    $(function() {
        $('div.gallery img').slidingGallery(); 
        start_autoslide();
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what else you are looking for with your bounty, but my recommendation is to use a carousel that does exactly what you want.

I have had nothing but good experiences with http://caroufredsel.frebsite.nl/. The author is quick to answer questions, add features, and even has a [setup wizard](http://caroufredsel.frebsite.nl/configuration-robot.php) to get the slideshow going with almost zero manual configuration.

There are options for it to be [circular, infinite, auto-play, keyboard driven, pause-on-hover, set cookies, changes directions, etc etc.](http://caroufredsel.frebsite.nl/configuration.php)

I'm not involved with the project at all, but this is the only gallery I'll use for my work.

Answer (score 0):

Call these methods yourself?

```
$.galleryUtility.slideRight( ) 
$.galleryUtility.slideLeft( )
```

Comment: You called those methods after your gallery was instantiated? Do you have a public URL to your implementation? My suggestion is based on the demos that they make available on the URL that you provided.

Comment: Go to the [demo](http://www.meadmiracle.com/SlidingGalleryDemo1.htm) from the page that you linked to. Open Firebug, in the console enter `$.galleryUtility.slideLeft( );`, and then click _Run_.

Comment: How can i program this to be called every 5 seconds or so?

Answer (score 0):

since it's Jquery, you can use "stepcarousel.js" → http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/stepcarousel.htm then you can include this line of code in your script to invoke the auto function.

```
autostep: {enable: true, moveby:1, pause:5000},
```

hope this helps...